# Why does C++'s exception not provide the calling details?

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    try {
        std::map<std::string, int> m{{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}};
        std::cout << m.at("c") << std::endl;
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In C++, when retrieving a non-existent key of a map, the exception looks like `map::at:  key not found`. Information about what the *key* is is not provided.

Also, if one is accessing a non-existent file, the exception message of `std::ios_base::failure` looks like `ios_base::clear: unspecified iostream_category error`. The *filename* which caused the exception is not provided. Thus it may take quite a time to find out where the exception is from if there are many `map.at()` or `ifstream is` uses in a project.

In contrast to this, Python may tell you `KeyError: 'c'` or `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'foo'`.

Is this just a C++ convention? Thank you.

Comment: Remember, in C++, the key of a map might not be convertible to a string.

Comment: The C# FileNotFoundException does also not mention the file name of the file which cannot be found

Comment: @nos: in the spirit of the stdlib you should probably say "does not have an op<<" but even then one could argue that it should maybe do this for all those types where it can. Imho the main reason is robustness: what happens if during trying to assemble a nice and dandy error message, you encounter another exception?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The issue is the C++ object model, which differs from Python's. To contrast, first let's answer: what does Python store in the exception object to print the key? It's a reference that keeps that object alive.

This cannot be done simply in C++.

1. `std::out_of_range` can't store a pointer or reference to the key as is. The handler for the exception may be in far away block. And that means that the key most probably went out of scope before the handler is entered. We get undefined behavior if the key is referred to.
2. `std::out_of_range` is a concrete class. Not a template like `std::map`. It can't easily copy the key into itself. There are many different `Key` types, and it obviously can't account for all of them. Even if it could, what if the key is extremely expensive to copy? Or even non-copyable at all? Even in cases where that's not true, what if the key isn't convertible to a string, or printable?

The above points don't mean it's impossible. `std::map::at` can throw a sub-class of `std::out_of_range` that does type erasure and so forth. But I hope you see it has non-trivial overhead. C++ is all about not paying in performance for features you don't need or use. Making everyone bear that overhead unconditionally isn't in line with this design.

Answer (score 3):

C++ standard specifies that `map::at(const key_type& k)` will launch a `std::out_of_range` exception (if value is not inside it); nothing more... but nothing less; a particular implementation of `map::at()` but the problem would be that the k's key_type have to be converted to char*.
So there are several options:

1. Do not show this information
2. `std::map` does not store types without (at least implicit) conversion to char*: but there would be a requirement applied to the key_store type that is not strict necessary
3. To provide different messages in `std::out_of_range` exception depending on the key_type: but this solution does not always show the expected information

In other point of view, `std::out_of_range` inherits from `std::logic_error`; C++ standard distinguishes between two main types of exceptions:

- logic_error: they are due to errors in the internal logic of the
  program. In theory, they are preventable.
- runtime_error: they are due to events beyond the scope of the program. They cannot be easily predicted in advance.

In our case, we can check the existence of an element easily (so our case fixes with this case)

Answer (score 0):

With C++,  it is possible to create a  personalized exception inheriting from std::exception with extra info, like filename. Here is an example :

```
#include <sstream>

class MyException : public std::exception {
  public :
  MyException (std::exception e, std::string filename = "") : std::exception (e), str_ (filename) {}
  MyException (const MyException& e) : std::exception (e), str_ (e.str_) {}
  const char* what () const throw () {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "exception occured in " << str_ << " : ";
    oss << std::exception::what ();
    return oss.str ().c_str ();
  }
  std::string str_;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    try {
      try {
          std::map<std::string, int> m{{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}};
          std::cout << m.at("c") << std::endl;
      }
      catch (const std::exception& e) {
          MyException f (e, "main");
          throw (f);
      }
    }
    catch (const MyException& e) {
      std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

will display :

```
exception occured in main : std::exception
```